# Grease pencil stroke disappears instantly after I draw

Tags: grease-pencil, layers

I was using grease pencil just fine, but then after I locked a layer(and selected another) I couldn't draw because my drawing strokes would instantly disappear. I've checked opacity, visibility, frames, and X-ray. I just don't know what to do! If you would like images or a video or the file feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not too much to go on but sounds like you nudged the frame number away from the frame the rest of your drawings were on. Check the timeline at the bottom of your workspace, is the green "current" indicator on the same frame as the keys?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't nudge the frame and created by mistake another keyframe (i.e. when you don't draw on the desired keyframe and draw on an empty space on the timeline), then delete your *Time Offset* modifier, the blue wrench icon under *Editor Type* on the right, and your keyframes will be back to normal and you will be able to edit them.